# Difference Callback, Promise and Event JavaScript/React-Native <-> Java/Android

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

I am reading about [native modules](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android) in React-Native and Android. 
The documentation distinguishes between

- [callbacks](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android#callbacks)
- [promises](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android#promises)
- [events](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android#sending-events-to-javascript)

I am having trouble understaind the difference between the three of them. What are the main differences and when is used what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A callback is a function that you pass to another function, which will then call that when some async action is done:

```
somethingAsync(function callback(result) { /*...*/ });
```

You will see this pattern quite often, as everything ilelse relies on callbacks. If you however got many callbacks, the code gets hard to read and to maintain, especially when working with loops. For that, Promises were introduced, which wrap a callback function, and allow to attach callbacks to the Promise. That allows for some nice chaining:

```
 const promise = new Promise(somethingAsync);
 promise.then(function result() { /*...*/ });
```

Note that a promise only resolves once, while callbacks can be called multiple times.

Events are not really related to Promises, they allow you to attach a callback to an object that will get called when something happens, e.g. a button gets clicked:

```
 button.onclick = function(event) { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: How can callback be called multiple times? If you try to call method from native part that returns multi callbacks you will get an error. As the documentation states: "A native module is supposed to invoke its callback only once. It can, however, store the callback and invoke it later.". So it is like with the promises, it will resolve once, but later you can call it again. Am I right? So it means promises as a communication between native and react is for cleaner code?

Comment: @m.wojcik nope, you took the documentation of one special callback somewhere and applied it to all callbacks. `[1, 2, 3].forEach(cb)` for example will call the callback `cb` three times.